# CS50x Readability improvement

Tags: c

I am brand new to writing my own code. I just started the CS50x intro class and have so far made it to pset 2 readability. It's getting easier to understand what's going on. I just wanted to get some opinions on the code that I wrote to see if there were possible improvements/changes that I could make.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>


//initialize lenght function
int length(string str, char check);

int main(void)
{
    //Get user input
    string input = get_string("Text: ");

    //Calculate and set grade level. Take user input and run it thorugh the lenght function. l for letters, w for words and s for sentances.
    float gradeLevel = (0.0588 * (100 * (float) length(input, 'l') / (float) length(input, 'w')) - 0.296 * (100 * (float) length(input, 's') / (float) length(input, 'w'))) - 15.8;

    //output grade level
    if (round(gradeLevel) >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }

    else if (round(gradeLevel) < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(gradeLevel));
    }


    //print lengths for testing
    /*
    printf("%i letter(s)\n", length(input, 'l'));
    printf("%i word(s)\n", length(input, 'w'));
    printf("%i sentance(s)\n", length(input, 's'));
    */
}

//function to get length of letters, words and sentences
int length(string str, char check)
{
    int letterCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 1;
    int senCount = 0;
    int n = strlen(str);

//check letter count
    if (check == 'l')
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(str[i]))
            {
                letterCount++;
            }
        }
        return letterCount;
    }
//check word count
    else if (check == 'w')
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t')
            {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        return wordCount;
    }
//check sentance count
    else if (check == 's')
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
            {
                senCount++;
            }
        }
        return senCount;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for the detailed feedback. Here's the specs of the program

Your program should count the number of letters, words, and sentences in the text. You may assume that a letter is any lowercase character from a to z or any uppercase character from A to Z, any sequence of characters separated by spaces should count as a word, and that any occurrence of a period, exclamation point, or question mark indicates the end of a sentence.

Your program should print as output "Grade X" where X is the grade level computed by the Coleman-Liau formula, rounded to the nearest integer.

If the resulting index number is 16 or higher (equivalent to or greater than a senior undergraduate reading level), your program should output "Grade 16+" instead of giving the exact index number. If the index number is less than 1, your program should output "Before Grade 1".

The algorithm used was the Coleman-Liau index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're off to a great start!  This is reasonably readable, and I'm sure you'll get better with practice.

---

```
lenght
```

Typo.  I make tons of typos myself.  I highly recommend getting an IDE with a spell checker.

---

```
string input = ...
```

This confused me at first.  It has to be a typedef, but what kind of typedef makes sense?  Turns out in `<cs50.h>`, they `typedef char *string;`.  This is a little weird to me because `char*` is a very familiar type -- I instantly know a few things to look for/what operations you can do with that.  `string` is an unknown entity.  I think `char* input = ...` is clearer.

---

```
float gradeLevel = (0.0588 * (100 * (float) length(input, 'l') / (float) length(input, 'w')) - 0.296 * (100 * (float) length(input, 's') / (float) length(input, 'w'))) - 15.8;
```

This line is so long!  Breaking it down and simplifying a bit:

```
float l_over_w = (float) length(input, 'l') / (float) length(input, 'w');
float s_over_w = (float) length(input, 's') / (float) length(input, 'w');
float gradeLevel = (5.88 * l_over_w - 29.6 * s_over_w) - 15.8;
```

1. I have no idea where the numbers 5.88, 29.6, and 15.8 came from.
2. Maybe the `div` function would help you instead of casting to float?  `float`s are slow and have a lot of idiosyncrasies... IMO they are best to avoid unless you absolutely MUST use them.
3. I find the general idea here non-obvious.  How about some comments?
4. This could be a function `float gradeLevel(char* input);`

---

```
int length(string str, char check)
```

You've used `check` to determine what this function should do.  That's generally a bad idea, but if you cannot avoid it, **at least** `assert(false)` if check is invalid.  That way you get a runtime error if `check` is wrong.  As you've written it, you'll silently get the wrong answer if `check` is wrong.

In this case, it is trivial to do better.  You could have several functions: `int letterCount(char* str);`, `int wordCount(char* str);`, and `int sentenceCount(char* str);`.  This way you get a compiler error if you write the wrong function name (and you can't get `check` wrong since `check` doesn't exist).

---

```
int letterCount = 0;
int n = strlen(str);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (isalpha(str[i])) {
        letterCount++;
    }
}
return letterCount;
```

This is OK, but you go over the string once to compute `strlen` and once to compute `letterCount`.  You can do them at the same time:

```
int letterCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
    if (isalpha(str[i])) {
        letterCount++;
    }
}
return letterCount;
```

I think this is also nicer since you don't have an `n` to worry about.  You could further simplify this to get rid of the index and just have the pointer:

```
while (str) {
    letterCount += isalpha(*str++);
}
```

but maybe that's overkill.

N.B. at least you didn't write `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)` which goes over the string once per character!

---

```
(str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t')
```

How about `isspace(str[i])`?

---

```
(str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '!' || str[i] == '?')
```

How about `ispunct(str[i])`?  Not an exact match so be careful.

Here's a list of similar functions available https://linux.die.net/man/3/ispunct.

---

```
//print lengths for testing
/* ...
```

This is totally fine for a personal project, but there are lots of testing frameworks that will always compile your test code but only run it under certain conditions.  Might be worth researching.  Here's a list to get you started https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.

---

Do you need to deallocate the string returned by `get_string`?

---

Is the number of words equal to the number of spaces?  What about this string `with         lots of white-spaces....`.  How many sentences are in that string?  I don't know the answer to these questions (maybe the exercise tells you what to compute?), but I think it's interesting to think about.

Comment: You are not the only one who is confused by the wrong `typedef` for `string`. See [here](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/163) and [here](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/175). Feel free to complain to these irresponsible teachers, they need to be told more often that they are wrong and that they are doing harm to their many students. :)

Comment: Appreciate the detailed feedback. I noticed a few of the items you pointed out has an * ie. char*. I need to look into what this actually does. In regards to separating the checks into their own functions, I was thinking better to consolidate into one. Is it generally ok to create multiple functions even if for small things? As for the typos thanks for pointing them out. Had no idea I had so many. I've taken your suggestion and setup codeblocks. Seems general consensus is this is a good IDE for beginners, although it's been quite a learning curve compared to the CS50 IDE I've been using.

Comment: Any ide you like is good.  I recommend trying a few now and again to try new features.  Small functions are fine -- do whatever is clearest by default.  When you're first starting out there will be things you don't understand/don't even notice (like pointers/typedefs).  Do try to learn them but when you're starting it's ok if you don't totally understand everything.  Still, learn the correct practices from the start and soon things will fall into place

Comment: *"letterCount += isalpha(*str++);"* - Yep, that's overkill

Answer (score 2):

**Indentation**

Much about indentation is a *style issue*.  Best to follow your group's style guide.  That said I would align comment with code.

```
//check letter count
    if (check == 'l')
```

to

```
    // check letter count
    if (check == 'l')
```

**Spell check**

Spelling errors are a distraction and a confusion.

**`double` vs. `float`**

In C, `double` is the default type for floating point constants like `0.0588`.  Code is going through lots of gyrations converting form `int` to `float` to `double` and back to `float`.  I suggest using `double` unless required to use `float` or code has *lots* of FP.

```
// float gradeLevel = (0.0588 * (100 * (float) length(input, 'l') / (float) length(input, 'w')) - 0.296 * (100 * (float) length(input, 's') / (float) length(input, 'w'))) - 15.8;
double gradeLevel = 0.0588 * (100.0 * length(input, 'l') / length(input, 'w'))
    - 0.296 * (100.0 * length(input, 's') / length(input, 'w')) - 15.8;
```

If staying with `float`, use `float` constants: `0.0588` --> `0.0588f`

**Rounding (advanced)**

`round()`returns a `double`.  C provides a nice way to round a *floating point* to an integer type in one step

```
long gradeLevel = lround(0.0588 * (100.0 * length(input, 'l') / length(input, 'w'))
    - 0.296 * (100.0 * length(input, 's') / length(input, 'w')) - 15.8);
...
printf("Grade %ld\n", gradeLevel);
```

Comment: Appreciate the review! Didn't realize I had so many typos lol. Definitely need to learn more about the different data types available.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite topics for code review and rants is the `<ctype.h>` header. It defines functions like `isalpha` that *sound* as if they would operate on characters (`char`), but they don't. They operate on numbers (`int`) instead, which is obviously confusing, but that's the way it is in C and C++.

The short answer is to never call `isalpha` with a `char` as argument. Always use an `unsigned char`, for example like this:

```
if (isalpha((unsigned char) str[i])) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to know more about the background, I've written [a lengthy answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60696378) that contains many more details.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at your previous answer.